# Template suggestion does not work for table in a custom block / Might there be a way around?

Tags: views, theming, blocks

I created a block on pages of the "Author" content type that lists all the articles the author has contributed to in a table (via contextual filter). Now I want to customize the table layout. I already did this before in a similar case, where I show the table on a page, not in a block. There I get file name suggestions for the template inside HTML comments like that:

```
<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'views_view_table__articles' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   x views-view-table--articles.html.twig
   x views-view-table--articles.html.twig
   * views-view-table.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/MYTHEMEFOLDER/templates/views/views-view-table--articles.html.twig' -->
```

But in my latest case, the table in a block, I only get this suggestion:

```
<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'views_view_table' -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/MYPARENTTHEMEFOLDER/templates/views/views-view-table.html.twig' -->
```

Note that it outputs the template of my parent theme, not my actual theme.

I did some research and found [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3062376), which currently is not resolved and the proposed patch not included inside the Drupal code. Is this the reason I cannot create a custom template or is there something else I can do?

If not, how would I create that table of referenced articles on the author's page?

Comment: Did you apply the patch yes or no? You can apply patches to your project yourself. You could probably also take the code from the patch and create a custom module for it. You could install Devel or use Xdebug to see what's in the $variables when adding another template suggestion for the views table.

Comment: No, I didn't apply the patch. But after your suggestion I tried implementing the code of the patch in a custom module, but then I realized this patch is probably for something else. I need template suggestions for "block--views-block--XYZ", but this patch adds only template suggestions for "block--block-content--XYZ". How can I use Devel or Xdebug to see what's in $variables?

Comment: I now created a custom module which simply adds the missing template suggestion, although I'm not sure if it's the right way. It works, but I think this should be fixed in the Drupal core code...? https://pastebin.com/4U3CNEEi

Comment: If you think it's a bug or feature missing from core, please report it in the issue queue on drupal.org

Comment: This definitely is the right way. Adding your own template suggestion in a custom module. Nice work!  Consider adding that as a proper answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Drupal doesn't suggest certain template file names I had to create a custom module which adds the template name for my needs. I had to implement the `hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK()` for my table view and add an appropriate name to the suggestions array.

```
<?php

use Drupal\views\ViewExecutable;

/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK().
 */
function custom_template_suggestions_theme_suggestions_views_view_table_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  if (isset($variables['view']) && $variables['view'] instanceof ViewExecutable) {
    $id = $variables['view']->current_display;

    if (!in_array('views_view_table__' . $id, $suggestions)) {
      $suggestions[] = 'views_view_table__' . $id;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: (I think you can also have that in your theme, but not 100% sure.)